# stomp_dart_client not connecting to server

Tags: spring-boot, flutter, sockets, websocket, stomp

Trying to set connection to my spring boot server in flutter app

```
final socketUrl = 'https://10.0.0.6:8443/notifications';
if (stompClient == null) {
      stompClient = StompClient(
          config: StompConfig.SockJS(
            url: socketUrl,
            onConnect: onConnect,
            onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString()),
          ));

      print(stompClient.config.url);

      stompClient.activate();
    }
```

but function onConnect is never called and i dont get any error message neither. I have tried change url to wss://10.0.0.6:8443/notifications and remove SockJs with same result. Also tried to connect to wss://echo.websocket.org without any success.

Web server is config as follow and it has valid certs

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class webSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/notification/item");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications");
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Calling socket from JS web app on same server is working fine.

I have tried other flutter libs (Stomp, Socket_IO, WebSocketChannel) to connect but without any success. Is there something I am missing in configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into problems with CORS. Please try only this line:

```
registry.addEndpoint("/notifications").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
```

while keeping the client as it is posted here.